# How to add id in tab infobubble

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need your help to add event clic into tab infobubble. This event should show an alert by clicking on the tab tab 1. The problem starts when I can not create an id on the tab

http://jsfiddle.net/hT8Kw/11/

```
map_initialize(); // load map
function map_initialize(){
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.286172, -121.80929),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.286172, -121.80929);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'A Customized InfoWindow Marker'
    });

    var  infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
      maxWidth: 300
    });

    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.innerHTML = 'Hello';

    infoBubble.addTab('Tab 1', div);
    infoBubble.addTab('Tab 2', "1234");

    //Add event clic into Tab 1. If click in Tab 1 show alert.

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      if (!infoBubble.isOpen()) {
        infoBubble.open(map, marker);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the id to tab 1 but the click event did not work.
Please write tab 1 like this.

```
infoBubble.addTab('<div onclick="myfunction();">Tab1</div>', div);

//tab 1 click event
function myfunction(){
　alert("Tab1");
}
```